# Programming wpf xaml vs windows rt with c# and xaml

Tags: winrt-xaml

Ok. I know wpf and am learning programming windows runtime via c# and xaml.
Both use xaml that have the same namespace. Win rt is new and has the same namespace declared at the root element.

What are the similarities and differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some of the differences between WPF and WinRT:

1. Different XML namespace declaration in XAML code (Instead of using a clr-namespace:/assembly= qualifier set for code-to-XAML namespace references, you use the using: qualifier. XAML namespaces no longer reference specific assemblies)
2. Missing Expression SDK in WPF
3. Missing Property-/DataTriggers in WPF
4. Reduced BindingMode enum
5. Missing Multi/Priority Binding in WPF
6. Missing RoutedCommands in WPF
7. Missing InputBindings in WPF
8. DependencyProperty value calculation goes without coercion and validation

There are lot more differences. You can check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229571.aspx) to know further.

Comment: Perfect buddy! The link specifies Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Are there any conversion tools to automate converting this?